# Сайт на Perl, как быть с index.html

Tags: веб-программирование, perl

Всем доброго времени суток!
В общем я не профессиональный WEB-разработчик, так, простенькое что нибудь если. И нужен был простенький сайт с разделом каталога товаров. Ну и наваял я все страницы на HTML/CSS там и прочее, а страницу каталога - соответственно на Perl(который контент из базы данных на сервере собирает), с выводом используя template, т.е. динамическая html-страничка получилась. И все бы хорошо, но аппетит приходит во время еды, и заказчик теперь хочет что бы на главной странице показывалось содержимое каталога! Если бы я знал PHP, проблем бы небыло, т.к. он встраивается прямо в код HTML. С Perl так не выйдет. И index.html в index.cgi не переименовать, если хостер такое позволяет. Бред это. Вот и вопрос, что делать? PHP изучать нету времени, переделывать с нуля как то вообще всё по другому - тоже. Через AJAX "рисовать" каталог в index.html? Каталог - менюшка с выскакивающими подменю на JavaScript текстовая. Пока что вижу это единственным выходом...
Может быть есть еще варианты? И главное, как отнесутся поисковики при индексации к такому index.html?
Спасибо!

Comment: что-то непонятно. А так критично, если в строке браузера будет написано не `index.html`, а `index.pl`? и вообще зачем там отображать `index`? Можно его просто скрыть и делать индексную страницу также на перле..... ..а если критично, то вообще с помощью `htaccess` можно  заменить в строке `.pl` на `.html` создав иллюзию что там html страница

Comment: да можно и так, но раз человек выбрал путь с перл + html то можно и SSI использовать но это оооочень старо. я например этим пользовался последний раз где то в 2006

Comment: если совсем-совсем просто - то можно в index.html вставить редирект на "правильную страницу". Но обычно подобные "проблемы" решают конфигом апача/нджинкса.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский Да "через китай" это как то... И потом у хостера разделены директории httpdocs и cgi-bin. В первой Perl работать не будет.

Comment: Дмитрий Гвоздь Согласен, старо. А я по другому и не умею - не моя основная специализация. Так, баловался когда то.

Comment: KoVadim как поисковики отнесутся к такому редиректу?

Comment: httpdocs и cgi-bin разделены везде. поисковики к этому отнесуться правильно, если оформить редирект верно.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо использовать банальное SSI программирование.
Переименуйте index.html в index.shtml и добавьте в код вашего index.shtml так назывемую SSI встаку.

[SSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Пример запуска PERL скрипта в shtml странице.

```
<!--#exec cgi="/counter.pl"-->.
```

Comment: И что, на месте <!--#exec cgi="/counter.pl"--> в HTML коде появится ответ counter.pl? Но в любом случае shtml тоже не подходит. Но спасибо за совет!

Comment: если shtml не подходит тогда включите поддержку SSI для обычных html страниц, Да если SSI включен и вы правильно укажете путь до вашего скрипта, должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет.
Ajax к оленям.
Вышел из положения так:
В .htaccess добавил строчку:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

в index.html прописал(примерно здесь)

```
<html>
...
<?php
$f = fopen("db", "r");
while(!feof($f)) {
<обработка строки> 
echo <Здесь вывожу HTML-строки кода менюшки с обработанной строкой>;
    }
 fclose($f);
?>
...
</html>
```

Буду потихоньку изучать PHP, что бы полностью перевести на него сайт.

P.S.
Модераторы, если я опять нарушил правила - прошу прощения, больше не буду писать ответ. Просто мне кажется, я указал решение к которому пришел, неважно какое оно в плане правильности, но для моей ситуации оно работает меньшей кровью.